# launchApplicationAtURL: crash

Tags: macos, nstask, nsworkspace

crash message:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff203c9f2a fileport_makeport + 10
1   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff20147373 _xpc_fileport_makeport + 9
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff20147334 xpc_fd_create + 27
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff201486cf xpc_dictionary_set_fd + 23
4   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff209ea050 _CASNotifyServerSideAboutLaunchedApplication(LSSessionID, __CFDictionary const*, int, __CFDictionary const*, int, bool, __CFDictionary const**) + 550
5   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff209ffe4c _LSLaunchWithRunningboard(LSContext*, FSNode*, unsigned int, void*, __CFArray const*, AEDesc const*, AEDesc const*, NSArray<LSSliceInfo*>*, __CFDictionary const*, unsigned int, audit_token_t const*, _LSOpen2Options const*, ProcessSerialNumber*, NSError* __autoreleasing*) + 24181
6   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff209f9e8e _LSLaunch + 171
7   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff2096f690 _LSOpenApp(LSOpenState*, unsigned int, FSNode*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, ProcessSerialNumber*) + 1135
8   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff2096d273 _LSOpenItemsWithHandler_CFDictionaryApplier(void const*, void const*, void*) + 1442
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204f3902 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 22
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204bbeae CFBasicHashApply + 110
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204ae71f CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 131
12  com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff2096bce0 _LSOpenStuffCallLocal + 9322
13  com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff20967dd1 _LSOpenStuff + 1641
14  com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff20a22898 _LSOpenApplication_Common(LSApplicationParameters_V1 const*, AEKeyDesc const*, ProcessSerialNumber*, __CFURL const**) + 168
15  com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff20a229a3 _LSOpenApplicationURL + 174
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff235c73d5 -[NSWorkspace launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:] + 330
17  libApplication.dylib            0x000000010c1e90fa Tools::os_create_process(char const*, char const*, char*) + 394
18  libApplication.dylib            0x000000010c1cd0b4 std::__1::__bind_return<Application::ExePluginProcessHost::Create(char const*, char const*, std::__1::function<void (int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)>)::$_1, std::__1::tuple<>, std::__1::tuple<>, __is_valid_bind_return<Application::ExePluginProcessHost::Create(char const*, char const*, std::__1::function<void (int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)>)::$_1, std::__1::tuple<>, std::__1::tuple<> >::value>::type std::__1::__bind<Application::ExePluginProcessHost::Create(char const*, char const*, std::__1::function<void (int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)>)::$_1&>::operator()<>() + 84
19  libApplication.dylib            0x000000010c1d1123 Application::ThreadTaskMgr::ProcessMainThreadTask() + 627
20  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010d2d385f QObject::event(QEvent*) + 111
21  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x000000010c4ee9ea QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 266
22  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x000000010c4efe11 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 497
23  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010d2a8a34 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 212
24  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010d30e35f QTimerInfoList::activateTimers() + 991
25  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0000000110a348f2 0x1109fc000 + 231666
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204f22bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204f2224 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 180
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204f1fa4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204f09cc __CFRunLoopRun + 893
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204eff8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
31  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff28737a83 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
32  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff287376b6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 284
33  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff28737583 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22cf9172 _DPSNextEvent + 864
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22cf7945 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1364
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22ce9c69 -[NSApplication run] + 586
37  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0000000110a3562f 0x1109fc000 + 235055
38  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010d2a4acf QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 431
39  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010d2a9042 QCoreApplication::exec() + 130
40  cn.xdf.gkroombox                0x000000010c166a60 main + 896
41  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20415f3d start + 1
```

I create some subApp from hostApp ,sometimes cause crash like it!!
I cant't find what's reason about it.
I konw GUARD_TYPE_FD and  from 0x4000001000000000 I konw it's subtype kGUARD_EXC_DUP  , however I did't understand it

Comment: look down with it

Answer (score 0):

```
Process:               Roombox [5679]
Path:                  /Applications/Roombox.app/Contents/Developer/Roombox.app/Contents/MacOS/Roombox
Identifier:            Roombox
Version:               2.7.0 (540)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           Roombox [5679]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-03-17 14:37:52.630 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 11.6.1 (20G224)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        91C26615-6D4C-81F1-B66C-D1315045ADE0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       FB29320A-F382-488C-B83F-490E94CAC8FE

Time Awake Since Boot: 16000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_GUARD
Exception Codes:       0x4000001000000000, 0x08fd4dbfade2dead
Exception Subtype:     GUARD_TYPE_FD, id=0x08fd4dbfade2dead, fd=0, flavor=0x00000010 (FILEPORT)
```

Comment: this is some message